# Installation of Bitcoin Core 0.18.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 error

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu, installation

I used "sudo snap install bitcoin-core" and it appeared to install fine except I get the error: "Failed to launch 'Bitcoin Core' Desktop file didn't specify Exec 
Field."  Did I do something wrong?  Maybe I am not finished with the install?

This is nearly a pristine installation of Ubuntu.  The only other thing I did was run updates and I installed Konsole prior to installing Bitcoin Core.  I ran the "sudo snap install..." command from Konsole.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must help you.

Open terminal:

```
$ sudo su
# cd /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications
# nano bitcoin-core_bitcoin-qt.desktop
```

and last line must look like that

```
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/bitcoin-core_bitcoin-qt.desktop /snap/bin/bitcoin-core.qt %U
```

`Ctrl + X` will quit the editor and you will be asked if you want to save your changes. Press `Y` for Yes.

Now try launching the app.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, I typed '/snap/bin/bitcoin-core.qt' and now Bitcoin Core is synchronizing with the network. Problem solved.

I still don't know how to repair the shortcut but that is because I'm a Linux newbie.